# How do you solve $\frac{d x}{dt} + kx = c\left(1 - e^{-\frac{kt}{2}}\right)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve $$\frac{d x}{dt} + kx = c\left(1 - e^{-\frac{kt}{2}}\right)$$
>
> where $k$ and $c$ are constants.
>
> Initial condition: $x(0)=0$

Are there a few general techniques I can deploy when coming across this type of problem again?

Thanks

Comment: Integrating Factor and Exact Equation come to mind.

Comment: oops. IC is x(0) = 0

Answer (score 1):

You have
$$x'(t) + k x(t) = c \left(1 - e^{-\frac{kt}{2}} \right),$$
so we can write it in the form
$$x'(t) + p(t) x(t) = q(t),$$ where
$$p(t) = k \quad \text{and}\quad q(t) = c\left(1 - e^{-\frac{kt}{2}} \right).$$

Then, using the Integrating Factor method, we have
$$x(t) = e^{-\int p(t) \mathrm{\, d}t } \int e^{\int p(t) \mathrm{\, d}t } q(t) \mathrm{\, d}t = c e^{-k t} \left(\frac{e^{k t}}{k}-\frac{2 e^{\frac{k t}{2}}}{k}\right)+ A e^{-k t}.$$
Finally, the point $x(0)=0$, determines $A=c/k$ then
$$x(t) =  \frac{c e^{-k t} }{k}  \left(e^{\frac{k t}{2}}-1\right)^2.$$

See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegratingFactor.html

Comment: Thanks, why is the integration constant A attached to an e^-kt term?

Answer (score 1):

1. Find the general solution of the homogeneous equation,

$$x'+kx=0,$$ then $$\frac{x'}x=-k$$ is separable and it suffices to integrate to get

$$\ln x=-kt+C,$$ or $$x=Ce^{-kt}.$$

2. Find a particular solution of the inhomogenous equation. You can separate the terms.

2a. For the constant RHS ($c$), simply try a constant

$$(D)'+kD=c\implies D=\frac ck.$$

2b. For the exponential term ($-ce^{-kt/2}$), try the same exponential with a coefficient,

$$(Ee^{-kt/2})'+kEe^{-kt/2}=\left(-\frac{kE}2+kE\right)e^{-kt/2}=-ce^{-kt/2}$$ giving

$$E=\frac{2c}k.$$

Finally, plug the initial condition to find the remaining unknown $C$:

$$Ce^{-k0}+\frac ck+\frac{2c}ke^{-k0/2}=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Well, let:

$$\rho\left(t\right):=\exp\left\{\int\text{k}\space\text{d}t\right\}\tag1$$

And, use:

$$\text{k}\cdot e^{\text{k}t}=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(e^{\text{k}t}\right)\tag2$$

So:

$$\text{x}'\left(t\right)+\text{k}\cdot\text{x}\left(t\right)=\text{c}\cdot\left(1-e^{-\frac{\text{k}t}{2}}\right)\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\int\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\text{x}\left(t\right)\cdot e^{\text{k}t}\right)\space\text{d}t=\int\text{c}\left(e^{\text{k}t}-e^{-\frac{\text{k}t}{2}}\right)\space\text{d}t$$